# Evaluating limits of function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Suppose that f is a function for which $\lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{f(x)}{x} = \ell$ where $\ell \in \mathbb R$ \ {0}. Evaluate, if possible,

$\lim_{x \to 1} \dfrac{f(x^{2014}-1)}{f(x^{2013}-1)}$.

I am guessing we will get something like $\dfrac{f(0)}{f(0)}$?

Comment: $$\frac{f(x^{2014}-1)}{f(x^{2013}-1)}=\frac{f(x^{2014}-1)}{f(x^{2013}-1)}\cdot \frac{x^{2013}-1}{x^{2014}-1}\cdot\frac{x^{2014}-1}{x^{2013}-1}=\frac{f(x^{2014}-1)}{x^{2014}-1}\cdot\frac{x^{2013}-1}{f(x^{2013}-1)}\cdot\frac{x^{2014}-1}{x^{2013}-1}$$

Comment: I am sorry, I am a little confused by the notations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\lim_{x \to 1} \dfrac{f(x^{2014}-1)}{f(x^{2013}-1)}=\lim_{x \to 1} \dfrac{f(x^{2014}-1)/(x^{2014}-1)}{f(x^{2013}-1)/(x^{2013}-1)}\cdot\frac{(x^{2014}-1)}{(x^{2013}-1)}=\frac{l}{l}\cdot\lim_{x \to 1}\frac{(x^{2014}-1)}{(x^{2013}-1)}=\lim_{x \to 1}\frac{(x^{2014}-1)}{(x^{2013}-1)}\overset{\text{L-Hopital}}{=}\lim_{x \to 1}\frac{2014x^{2013}}{2013x^{2012}}=\frac{2014}{2013}$$

Comment: So after the bunch of calculations we went back to the original question?

Comment: @Su003 What part do not you understand?

Comment: So you did a bunch of calculations on the first line but then at the end, it equaled the same thing that the question asked originally. This confused me.

Comment: @Su003 Note that:$$\lim_{x \to 1} \dfrac{f(x^{2014}-1)}{f(x^{2013}-1)}\neq\lim_{x \to 1}\frac{(x^{2014}-1)}{(x^{2013}-1)}$$

Comment: Oh okay! Am sorry, I misread that. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: $$\lim_{x \to 1} \dfrac{f(x^{2014}-1)}{f(x^{2013}-1)}=\frac{f(0)}{f(0)}$$ but $$\lim_{x \to 1} \dfrac{(x^{2014}-1)}{(x^{2013}-1)}=\frac{0}{0}$$ They are different indeterminations.

Comment: Ok so from l'Hopital rule we get the answer to be 2014/2013 right?

Comment: @Su003 Yes is correct.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Is there any way of solving this without using l'Hopital's rule?

Comment: @Su003 Yes Note that;$$x^n-1=(x-1)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}+\cdots+x^2+x+1)$$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18716/discussion-between-su003-and-asdrubalbeltran).